# load .yml file in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use config.yml in R. But whenever I load the file using

my config file looks like this

```
default: 
   dataconnection: 
     driver: 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server' 
     server: 'server' 
     uid: 'Username' 
     pwd: 'password' 
     port: 1433 
     database: 'Data_Science' 

rsconnect: 
  dataconnection: 
    driver: 'FreeTDS' 
    server: 'server' 
    uid: 'username' 
    pwd: 'password' 
    port: 1433 
    database: 'Data_Science'
```

Code:

```
config <- config::get(file = "C:/Users/Samuel.Golomeke/Documents/Data Science/Codes/R codes/SQL_Server_shiny_connect/config")
```

I keep getting the following warning message:

> Warning message:
>   In readLines(con) :
>     incomplete final line found on 'C:\Users\Samuel.Golomeke\Documents\Data Science\Codes\R codes\SQL_Server_shiny_connect\config.yaml'"

why is that?

Comment: Please post your config.yaml, especially the final line. As the warning message reads: the final line of yout config.yaml is considered incomplete...

Comment: default:
  dataconnection:
    driver: 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server' 
    server: 'server'
    uid: 'Username'
    pwd: 'password'
    port: 1433
    database: 'Data_Science'


    
rsconnect:
  dataconnection:
    driver: 'FreeTDS'
    server: 'server'
    uid: 'username'
    pwd: 'password'
    port: 1433
    database: 'Data_Science'

Comment: Please include it in your question, as a comment it is quite unreadable :-)

Comment: @sammgolo Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 8):

Make sure the last line in the config.yaml file has a blank line with no whitespace (space, tab, etc).